# How do I configure FUJI XEROX DocuCentre-IV C2275 properly? (Test Page printout failed)

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, firmware

Ubuntu 16.04 successfully found the 'FUJI XEROX DocuCentre-IV C2275' network printer and successfully initiated a Test Page printout. However, the printout was gibberish and was more than a dozen pages. I had to cancel the print job at the machine because the Print Queue was showing as empty. Doesn't this imply a driver problem?

I followed the default installation, but in the Printers window it is shown with both a green checkmark and a red exclamation point. What does this mean? (Apparently the red exclamation point means there is no toner left: Ink/Toner Levels has a Status Message also with a red exclamation point. A different computer, Mac, says it's low on toner.)

Some properties:

> Make and Model: Generic PCL 3 Printer Foomatic/pcl3 (recommended)
>
> Installable Options - Model: Unspecified Model

Do I need to specify a particular model under 'Installable Options'? How do I get it printing properly?

Comment: in that MAKE & MODEL option; click on the CHANGE button to the right; (drag the window to the right to better read it .. ) .. wait for the database to find the list of manufacturers .. click on the Fuji Xerox option; they offer several variants .. if you select them one by one; do they do better?

Comment: "Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM305 df Foomatic/Postscript (recommended)" successfully printed most of the test page, instead of generating 100+ pages of gibberish. However, although it correctly printed a rectangular border near the edge of the page, the string "Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM305 df Foomatic/Postscript" ran off the page as "Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM305 df Foomatic/Posts", the right edge border bisecting the 's', the string's remainder missing. So there is a sizing or text formatting problem with this driver or with its test page. Should I report this as a bug? (I'll try using this driver.)

Comment: do; engage with the folks who support these drivers; there are several variants; eg http://www.openprinting.org/driver/foo2hbpl2